# Maximum length of each word in BIP39

Tags: solidity, mnemonic, bip39

I wanted to render list of mnemonic phrases but in case of overflowing the text I wonder what is actually the character with longest length in BIP39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a list of mnemonic phrases in English, the maximum word length is 8 characters. There are 2048 words in the dictionary.

In other languages, the maximum word length may be different.